# Can display a GIF in <img> tag causing Client-side DOS

Tags: web-browser, denial-of-service, html, client-side, image

SVG image can be used in DOS user browser with [billion laugh attack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/161735/svg-files-and-billion-laughs-attack). Can we do the same with other image types? especially GIF?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly, though not so dramatically. The real trick of billion laughs attacks is that they're exponential: increasing the number of layers of recursion increases the total size (for the classic example) by a factor of 10. That's much more impressive than usual expansion relationships, such as linear (doubling input doubles the size) or quadratic (doubling input quadruples the size). As far as I know, no image format - definitely not GIF - allows the recursive expansion necessary for such exponential growth.

With that said, GIF is a compressed format, and thus you can attempt [decompression bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb) with it. Formats that allow more dramatic compression will do better, but GIF might still do something interesting. There exist sites around the Internet, such as [this one](https://bomb.codes/bombs), which store decompression bombs for testing purposes. They have what they claim is a 100Kx100K GIF - which would take 10GB even at only 256 colors, if you tried to expand it to a bitmap - that is only 7MB (after removing the BZ2 compression). That's not a *small* image but it's not enormous; some sites will let you host bigger than that. Similarly, 10GB isn't an enormous amount of memory - many PCs and I think some phones have at least that much RAM these days - but it could certainly choke a lower-resource machine.

Comment: Thank you, that is very informative. I will definitely take a look at GIF bomb and do some experiment with it.